# regex in python translation

Tags: python, regex

im just getting to grips with how regex works in python but some of the syntax is kind of throwing me a bit.

how would you translate the following regex into a regex that can be used by the re module in python?

```
a(b|c)*a
```

it doesnt matter what the symbols are, i am more asking about the brackets and operators, how they work.

if i was to be specific about my situation, i am trying to capture all text from between two angle brackets. according to some resources that i have read, the "." character matches any character except newline, and "s" matches any whitespace, including newline, so i thought the way to do it would be:

```
<[.|s]*>
```

but evidently i was wrong.

i am interested in a solution for my specific problem, but any general information on the operators in python regex would be appreciated also.

**EDIT:**

after more experimenting it seems to work when i use:

```
<.*>
```

when i have text like

```
<foo bar>
```

but not for when i have

```
<foo
bar>
```

however when i try

```
<[\n.]*>
```

nothing works. and so i thought it might be the brackets doing it or something so i tried:

```
<[.]*>
```

and that didnt even work like `<.*>` .. but surely, the two are the same except for the brackets..

anyone have any ideas? i'd like to be able to capture all text like:

```
<foo
bar>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The python regular expression syntax is clearly documented here:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

For your particular case, I'd try something like:

```
import re
pat = re.compile('<([^>]*)>')
match = pat.search('Foo <bar> bam')
print match.groups()
# should print ('bar',)
```

To understand the regular expression, we can break it down into its component parts:

- < - match the left-angle bracket
- ( - start of a group
- [^>]* - match 0 or more characters (*) in the class ([^>]).  A character class ([])
  that starts with a caret (^) means match characters that are not part
  of the class.  In this case the class consists of the single
  character, right-angle bracket (>).
- ) - end the group
- > - match the right-angle bracket

Comment: thanks, that worked. i did read through the documentation before posting here, but it seemed to suggest to me that what i was trying should work so i was kind of bashing my head against a wall.. it didnt occur to me to take the compliment of the class.. thats a good trick to know.. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

`a(b|c)*a` is directly usable as a Python re. `<[.|s]*>` is a confused mess.  `[`...`]` is a character range: `|` has no business inside.  `s` does not denote a space in Python regular expressions; instead `\s` does.  Maybe you are confusing `|s` with `\s` here (but it would make more sense to use just `\n` here and/or use the respective flags to have `.` also match a newline).

Comment: i was using the bar to denote the "or" operator as in the regular expressions used in formal languages, i didnt realise i needed the escape character sorry.. so `<[\n.]*>` should work then? if i have something like: 
`<foo\n bar>`?